# PHP mySQL query doesn't work - why?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I made a simple search with php and javascript but for some reason it returns the 'not found message'. I've checked the conection with the DB and the SELECT and everything is working fine. Anyone have an idea of which might be the problem?

obs: There are some word in portuguese but they have no function, they're just names and messages.

Here is the html code:

```
      <form method="post" action="pesquisar" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 mr-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Search for...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnBusca" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
     <div class="resultados">
    </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  $('form[acao="pesquisar"]').submit(function() {
  var req = $.post('busca.php',$(this).serialize());
    $('button[type="submit"]').attr("value","buscando");
req.done(function(data) {
  $('button[type="submit"]').attr("value","Buscar");
  $('.resultados').empty();

  $('.resultados').append(data);
});

return false;
  });
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
  $aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','u534499794_ehall');
  if(isset($_POST['busca']) && trim($_POST['busca']) != "" ){
    $busca = htmlspecialchars($_POST['busca']);
    $qr = mysqli_query($aVar,"SELECT * FROM dados WHERE titulo LIKE '%busca%' || conteudo like '%busca%' ") or die(mysql_error());

      if(mysqli_num_rows($qr) > 0) {
        $dados = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)) {
          array_push($dados,$row);
        }
        $dados1 = "";
        foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
          foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            $dados1 .= "$value1<br>";
          }
          $dados1 .= "<br>";
        }
        $m = array(
          'status'=>'sucesso',
          'msg'=>$dados1
        );
        echo $m['msg'];
      }else{
        $m = array(
          'status'=>'erro',
          'msg'=>'Nada encontrado'
        );
        echo $m['msg'];
      }

  }else{
    $m = array(
      'status'=>'erro',
      'msg'=>'Digite algum texto'
    );
    echo $m['msg'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: When you say "the not found error" what error are you specifically referring to? Is it possible to post the error as close to intact as you can?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface as you've already done here. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Switching the query to `WHERE titulo LIKE ? OR conteudo LIKE ?` and properly binding placeholders *will* fix this problem.

Comment: `'%busca%'` should be `'%$busca%'`

Comment: `mysql_error` is not helping you. You need to use all `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the tips, and especially to @Yolo thanks man, it worked.